# Chain rule by Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Please, how to evaluate dh(g(x))/dg(f(x)) by the following definitions:

```
f[x_] := x^4 - 1
g[f[x] _] := Log[f[x] + Sqrt[f[x]^2 - 1]]/Sqrt[f[x]^2 - 1]
h[g[x] _] := 1 + g[x]
```

Comment: Define `g` as `g[x_] := ...` and `h` as `h[x_] := ...`.  Then `D[h[x], x]` seems to work.

Comment: but differentiation wrt g(f(x)) is required @ChrisK

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that.  I'm not sure what dh(g(x))/dg(f(x)) means, so hopefully someone else answers!

Comment: many thanks @Chris K

Comment: With @ChrisK instructions on `g` and `h` then does not `FullSimplify@D[g[f[x]], x]` provide the answer you are seeking?

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Emad! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
f[x_] := x^4 - 1;
g[x_] := Log[x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1]]/Sqrt[x^2 - 1];
h[x_] := 1 + x;
D[h@g@x, x] / D[g@f@x, x] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Thank you @Somos . It works